# Render asp:menuitems as links

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a asp:menu define like so:

```
    <div id="MenuContainer" runat="server" class="menuContainer">
        <asp:Menu ID="DefaultMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource" SkinID="TopMenu" OnMenuItemDataBound="DefaultMenu_MenuItemDataBound" OnMenuItemClick="DefaultMenu_MenuItemClick" DynamicPopOutImageTextFormatString="" >
            <DataBindings>              
                <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" NavigateUrlField="Url" TextField="Title" ToolTipField="Description" />
            </DataBindings>
        </asp:Menu>
        <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="WebserviceSiteMapProvider" />
    </div>
```

The menu items are generated from a SiteMapDataSource as seen above. When rendered all the menu links are postbacks which then redirect to the relevant page:

```
protected void DefaultMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(e.Item.DataPath);
        }
```

Anyone know any easy way to render the menu items as hyper links rather than postbacks?

I ask as this is adding an unnecessary round-trip to my application which on a specific customer set-up is causing performance issues. I've been searching around on the internet all morning for this and can't really see any obvious.

Note: This is .Net 3.5 that is being used.

If I'm missing something please just say.

Nevermind, one of my colleagues showed me the issue, the sitemapdatasource was not returning a url therefore the links where being rendered as postbacks rather than hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use:

```
OnMenuItemClick="DefaultMenu_MenuItemClick"
```

that will create a postback, you need to build a control without it.

Here is a link to an answer with a simpler usage of menu for a sitemap, it might be worth a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030609/2366880